# Load balancing using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, load-balancing

I know it's a clickbait title, but this is a serious question. Recently, in Sri Lanka, the government deployed [https://fuelpass.gov.lk/](https://fuelpass.gov.lk/login) application where a Sri Lankan can register and check the fuel available for the registered vehicle. (The system was designed to control the amount of fuel available to an individual as fuel imports have slowed down due to the economic crisis).

When I checked the system yesterday I realized that they have deployed the dev build to production. As I was going through the code, I noticed that in the `Login` component, there is a `setTimeout` call on the form submit to show a loading animation.

The login component looked something like this:

```js
export default () => {
    const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState(false)

    return(
        <Loading showLoading = {waiting}>
            <form onSubmit = {() => {
                setWaiting(true)

                setTimeout(async () => {
                    await loginRequestCall()
                    setWaiting(false)
                }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)
            }}>
                <input />
                <button>Send OTP</button>
            </form>
        </Loading>
    )
}
```

Screenshot of the source code:
[image]

The important part is, when user clicks on the `Send OTP`, It shows the loading screen, only after waiting a random amount of time it sends the request.

I created a video about this and it kinda went viral in Sri Lanka. According to the comments, some of the justifications (for using `setTimeout` with a random amount of time to wait) were following.

1. It is a mechanism to prevent DDos attacks
2. Way to prevent users spamming Send OTP button causing multiple requests
3. It is a cheap way of load balancing (way to reduce the number of OTP requests)

I wouldn't think if someone wanted to DDos they would be dumb enough to use UI automation. There is no need of setTimeout to prevent spam also.

Which leave me with the last point.

So my questions are,

1. Is it possible to load balance using `setTimeout`?
2. If so, how exactly would it distribute the load?
3. Is there a valid reason to add a `setTimout`?

Comment: Usually services sending OTP's provide you with a timeout until you can send another OTP. So for that period of time you can disable the Send OTP button. I am assuming maybe the service used here might not have that timeout functionality built at the backend. So the frontend guy might have used this trick to achieve that.

Comment: funny enough i saw this video

Comment: @PratikWadekar The OTP timeout in this application is 2 min. In the frontend, timout amount was the exact one I used. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000)`. So it's going to be less than 5 seconds max. And it is called even the very first time. It must to be the load balancing the developer was thinking about.

Comment: @s1n7ax no i just saw this question here on random and saw the words "fuelpass"

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to load balance using setTimeout?**

> Load balancing is the process of distributing network traffic across multiple servers.

Since load balancing is not reducing the number of calls but distributing them, it is not possible to do load balancing using `setTimeout`

**If so, how exactly would it distribute the load?**

As I mentioned, it is impossible to do so with `setTimeout`, at least not in a non-hacky and inefficient manner.

**Is there a valid reason to add a setTimout?**

In my opinion, this `setTimeout` might be intended to be used as a `debounce` function to avoid the user clicking on the `OTP` button multiple times if the feedback is not provided immediately (but still not doing the work since all calls will be done anyway).

So the answer is **NO**, in my opinion, there is not any valid reason for this `setTimeout`